# FlowCover - draw images onto the screen for the first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to know how to make the FlowCoverView be drawn when I want it to (after images are obtained). http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m

I have tried [FlowCoverView draw] but that gives me an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to dynamically update the flowcover so I created a redraw method in FlowCoverView and then call it from the view controller when the data source changes.

```
- (void)redraw {
    [cache emptyCache];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [self draw];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an IBOutlet in your controller for the FlowCoverView in your nib file and connect them.
Then call [self.flowCoverView draw] when you want to refresh the view.